# How PWA works with Back4app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, angular10, back4app

Recently i use Back4app with angular 10 , can any help regarding how to implement PWA to work my app offline as well, so my application can be accessible offline

Comment: Take a look at Parse JS SDK local datastore: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#local-datastore

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks for comments let me check